# Find last JSON entry with value starting with

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I need to find the key of last property starting with a string

**JSON:**

```
var data = {
    "admin": "peterson",
    "worker": "peter napier",        
    "housekeeper": "peterson",
    "worker": "richard Ben",
    "executive": "richard parker",
    "executive": "peter alp",
    "housekeeper": "richard johny",
    "admin": "richardson"
};
```

I have to write an algorithm which will return the key corresponding to the last occurence of value starting with a string.

Ex: I need to get `admin` if I call `findKey("richard")`
    I need to get `executive` if I call `findKey("peter")`

I have iterated the object using simple for loop as this

```
for (var key in yourobject) {
  console.log(key, yourobject[key]);
}
```

But I like to know the fastest way of iterating this as my scenario has more than 100000 property.

Comment: By "last", you mean the one whose key is the greatest ?

Comment: Why is "data" not an array?

Comment: Algorithm : iterate, when it matches, keep the key if it's greater than the stored key or is the first matching key.

Comment: @dystroy iterate in reverse and find the first occurrence sounds simpler.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Assuming you have an order or you change the data structure (which is probably a sound idea)

Answer (score 1):

Just iterate over your data and store each name beginning with your key :

```
function findkey(name) {
  var lg = name.length,
      found;

  for(var line in data) {
    if(data[line].length >= lg && data[line].substring(0,lg) === name) {
      found = line; 
    }
  }

  return found;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

```
var findKey = function (string) {
    var keyToReturn;
    for(key in data){
        if(data[key].indexOf(string) === 0)
            keyToReturn = key;
    }
    return keyToReturn;
}
```